# Android error with download via wifi but OK on data (3G)

Tags: android, download, wifi

I used these code to download a mp3 file from sever:

```
URL u = new URL(link);
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
c.setRequestMethod("GET");
c.setDoOutput(true);
c.connect();
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(root,"Video.mp4"));


InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len1 = 0;
while ( (len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
     f.write(buffer,0,len1);
}
f.close();
```

It's work as expected via mobile data (3G), but when I try download via wifi, LogCat show:

```
06-08 22:36:49.892: W/System.err(347): java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: dl2.mp3.zdn.vn:80
06-08 22:36:49.902: W/System.err(347):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1038)
06-08 22:36:49.902: W/System.err(347):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:62)
06-08 22:36:49.902: W/System.err(347):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:88)
06-08 22:36:49.902: W/System.err(347):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:927)
06-08 22:36:49.902: W/System.err(347):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:909)
06-08 22:36:49.902: W/System.err(347):     at binh.book.Book$1.run(Book.java:60)
06-08 22:36:49.902: W/System.err(347):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)  
06-07 21:34:59.306: W/System.err(9686):     at binh.pronunciation.DownloadFiles$1$1.run(DownloadFiles.java:62)
```

in this code:

```
c.connect();
```

any help?
Thank!

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace as the type of error is important, too

Comment: Thank, I don't know what is the complete stack trace as the type of error, could you help me how to show it? Thank again!

Comment: You should see the same pattern like the line you posted: All of them starting with "    at". This is the stack trace. Right above the first line starting with "    at" you should see the error message which should be a phrase or sometimes even a sentence. So basically copy these line and past it here.

Comment: Thank @WarrenFaith, please see down, in 1st answer!

Comment: I have copied the stacktrace from the deleted answer. You should always edit your question and not post new information as an answer. This Q&A doesn't work like a forum :). Anyway have you checked that your wifi DNS can resolve the url `dl2.mp3.zdn.vn:80`? Looks like your wifi blocks that url somehow.

Comment: thank, I'm a newbie! I tried many different link & sever, but it not work, too :(

Comment: But you can access the internet over your wifi with the phone? Tried it using the device browser?

Comment: yes, it work as expected in other app like: opera mini browser, maps, gmail,... but only my app has problem :-S

Answer (score 0):

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved:
```

This exception is also raised when you are connected to a valid wifi but router does not receive the internet. Its very easy to reproduce this:
1) Connect to a valid wifi
2) Now remove the cable from the router while router is pluged-in

You will observe this error!!